# How to append a dataframe row to another within a for loop using .loc?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have the following dataframes:

```
df_t1 = pd.DataFrame([["AAA", 1 ,2],["BBB", 0, 3],["CCC", 1, 2],["DDD", 0, 0],["EEE", 0, 3]], columns=list('ABC'))

    A   B   C
0   AAA 1   2
1   BBB 0   3
2   CCC 1   2
3   DDD 0   0
4   EEE 0   3
```

and

```
df_t2 = pd.DataFrame([["XXX", 4, 1],["YYY", 5 ,6],["ZZZ", 0, 3]], columns=list('ABC'))

    A   B   C
0   XXX 4   1
1   YYY 5   6
2   ZZZ 0   3
```

I can locate the rows in df_t1 that meet a certain condition using the code below:

```
df_t1.loc[(df_t1['B'] <= 2) & (df_t1['C'] > 2)]

A   B   C
1   BBB 0   3
4   EEE 0   3

df_t1.loc[(df_t1['B'] <= 3) & (df_t1['C'] > 3)]

    A   B   C
[Empty Dataframe]
```

I can create a for loop that returns those same results:

```
for i in value_check:
    print(df_t1.loc[(df_t1['B'] <= i) & (df_t1['C'] > i)])

A  B  C
1  BBB  0  3
4  EEE  0  3
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B, C]
Index: []
```

But when I try to use that code to attach those values to df_t2:

```
value_check = [2,3]

for i in value_check:
    df_t2.append(df_t1.loc[(df_t1['B'] <= i) & (df_t1['C'] > i)])
```

df_t2 is unchanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pd.concat`

```
df_t1 = pd.DataFrame([["AAA", 1 ,2],["BBB", 0, 3],["CCC", 1, 2],["DDD", 0, 0],["EEE", 0, 3]], columns=list('ABC'))

df_t2 = pd.DataFrame([["XXX", 4, 1],["YYY", 5 ,6],["ZZZ", 0, 3]], columns=list('ABC'))

value_check = [2, 3]

for i in value_check:
    condition = (df_t1['B'] <= i) & (df_t1['C'] > i)
    row_to_add = df_t1.loc[condition]

    df_t2 = pd.concat([df_t2, row_to_add], axis=0)
```

Comment: Just be careful concatenating in a loop, as you will be concatenating each time you loop. So you will end up with a df that has `df_t2` appended n times (where n is the number of iterations in the loop) which is probably not the result OP wants.

Comment: Hhm i thought pd.concat creates a new copy and in my answer i assign that new concatenates dataframe to the variable and so it does not return the n-times-appended df_t2, but rather df_t2 with additional rows

Answer (score 1):

From the docs, the append method: "Appends rows of other to the end of this frame, returning a *new* object". You have to use assign `df_t2` in your loop:

```
value_check = [2,3]

for i in value_check:
    df_t2 = df_t2.append(df_t1.loc[(df_t1['B'] <= i) & (df_t1['C'] > i)])
```

That said, concatenating is more efficient.

Edit: Here is a implementation using concatenation and list comprehension

```
df_t2 = pd.concat([df_t2] + [df_t1.loc[(df_t1['B'] <= i) & (df_t1['C'] > i)] for i in value_check], axis=0)
```